# pandas: How to plot the pie diagram for the movie counts versus genre of IMDB movies in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, imdb

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'movie' : ['A', 'B','C','D'], 
                   'genres': ['Science Fiction|Romance|Family', 'Action|Romance',
                              'Family|Drama','Mystery|Science Fiction|Drama']},
                  index=range(4))
df
```

**My attempt**

```
# Parse unique genre from all the movies
gen = []
for g in df['genres']:
    gg = g.split('|')
    gen = gen + gg
    gen = list(set(gen))

print(gen)

df['genres'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
```

I got this image:
[image]

But I would like to pie chart for each separate genres.

How we get the genres for number count of movies for each unique genres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `.str.split()` with `expand=True`, which will give you a `DataFrame` of all the genres. If you then stack that, you will get the value counts for all of the genres.

```
df.genres.str.split('|', expand=True).stack().value_counts().plot(kind='pie', label='Genre')
```

[image]

That can be a bit on the slower side to calculate the counts, so a faster implementation for the same plot would be (adding the percentages):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.genres.str.split('|').values))
_ = plt.pie(cts.values(), labels=cts.keys(), autopct='%1.0f%%')
_ = plt.ylabel('Genres')
```

[image]

Comment: Can we also show the percentage number in pie chart ?

Comment: @astro123 yes, see the edit. Using `matplotlib` you just need to add the `autopct='%1.0f%%'` argument to the piechart.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million @ALollz. Quich question, this only counts the genres. if we have to plot  similar plot for  df.budget versus df.genre_unique_like_this HOW CAN WE DO THAT?

Comment: If that needs to be  a different question, i will post it.

Comment: @astro123 I think it might be better for a different question! I sadly also don't have the time to answer now. But I can check on it later.

Answer (score 8):

So, the one-liner solution:

```
df.genres.str.get_dummies().sum().plot.pie(label='Genre', autopct='%1.0f%%')
```

Result:

[image]

---

**TL;DR**

Firstly, convert your categories column to dummies:

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('genres', axis=1), df.genres.str.get_dummies()], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  movie  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0     A  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
1     B  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
2     C  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
3     D  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
```

Then count number of occurrences for each category:

```
counts = df.drop('movie', axis=1).sum()
```

Result:

```
a    2
b    2
c    2
d    1
e    2
f    1
g    1
```

And finally plot the pie chart:

```
counts.plot.pie()
```

[image]