# Pandas: How to plot the imdb movie total budget versus the separate genre in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is actually a follow up question to my previous question.

[pandas: How to plot the pie diagram for the movie counts versus genre of IMDB movies in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132970/pandas-how-to-plot-the-pie-diagram-for-the-movie-counts-versus-genre-of-imdb-mo)

In that question, we plotted the number of uniques genres for the movies.
My question is: How to get the `'budget'` versus `'genres'` plot in `pandas`?

Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'movie' : ['A', 'B','C','D'],
                   'budget': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
                   'genres': ['Science Fiction|Romance|Family', 'Action|Romance',
                              'Family|Drama','Mystery|Science Fiction|Drama']},
                  index=range(4))
df
```

Here genre `Science Fiction|Romance|Family` is actually three separate genres.

The `Science Fiction` appears in moives `A` and `B` so the budget for the genre `Science Fiction` should be `1000+4000=5000` and so on.

Comment: Use `df.plot(x='genres', y='budget')` for a simple line plot. Just go through [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) for more details.

Comment: You should try to put your question and what you want more *clearly* in the first go. This saves everyone's time from making edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can barplot total budget for each genre:

```
genres = (df.genres.str.split('|', expand=True)
            .stack()
            .to_frame(name='genre'))


genres.index = genres.index.droplevel(1)
```

So `genres` becomes:

```
        genre
0   Science Fiction
0   Romance
0   Family
1   Action
1   Romance
2   Family
2   Drama
3   Mystery
3   Science Fiction
3   Drama
```

Now perform a join and groupby to first get budget info, then sum on genre:

```
(genres.join(df['budget'])
       .groupby('genre')
       .sum()
       .plot(kind='bar'))
```

**Output:**

[image]